# Can I embed <PRE> tag into <P> tag?

Tags: javascript, getelementsbytagname

why are there two elements of `<p>` when i use only one `<p>` tag?

if `<center>` tag is instead of `<pre>`,the result is the same.

if `<b>` tag is instead of `<pre>`,the result of a.length is 1.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
  <p><pre>name: id:</pre></p>
<script>
  a = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
  document.write("LEN:"+a.length+"<BR>");
  for(i=0;i<a.length;i++){
    document.write(a[i].innerHTML+"<BR>");
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Please don't post images of code. Copy paste your code in question.

Comment: As @RiteshKhandekar says, please don't post images in the future unless absolutely necessary, Read [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question) to understand why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<pre>` cannot be inside `<p>`. Thus, when the HTML parser encounters `<pre>` inside `<p>`, it will close `<p>` first. Then it encounters `</p>`, a closing tag without an opening tag, and assumes you wanted `<p>`. The resulting structure is:

```
<p></p>
<pre>...</pre>
<p></p>
```

How do you know `<pre>` cannot be inside `<p>`? See `<p>` on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/p), or even better [in HTML spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/grouping-content.html#the-p-element), and notice "Permitted content: Phrasing content". Looking at what "phrasing content" is, you can see that it does not include `<pre>`.